# Tensor dot: deep learning with python

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication, tensor

I am currently reading **Deep Learning with Python** where I am not sure what the author is trying to say on page 42. The link is [here](https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/9/748519f-e25e-4426-826f-5a9f27485028/SampleCh02.pdf)

> More generally, you can take the dot product between higher-dimensional tensors,
>       following the same rules for shape compatibility as outlined earlier for the 2D case:
>
> ```
> (a, b, c, d) . (d,) -> (a, b, c)
> (a, b, c, d) . (d, e) -> (a, b, c, e)
> ```

Not sure what he is trying to say here. I do understand how matrix multiplication works but the above two lines of code is not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following this notation, matrix multiplication is

```
(a, b) * (b, c) -> (a, c)
```

When the second matrix is a vector, it simplifies to

```
(a, b) * (b, ) -> (a, )
```

Now, the formulas from the book simply explain how to *extend this operation*, when the first or second matrix has extra dimensions. It's important that both have a matching dimension (the last dim == the first dim, without reshaping), along which the tensors can be multiplied, eliminating this dimension. Hence, the formula for the result shape:

```
(a, b, c, d) * (d, e) -> (a, b, c, e)
```

Comment: Thank you, now I understand that the author is talking about dimensions which wasn't clear to me from the context.